# [skmaps][android]Pinch to zoom crashes app

Tags: android, skmaps

I've just started evaluating scobbler/scout for a project and I've run into a problem.

I've set up a single activity to display a map using the Skobbler SDK 2.3.0 on Android, API Level 18 (IDE=Android Studio 1.0.2). The map displays and can be panned, but pinch to zoom always kills the app immediately with the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.skobbler.ngx.map.MapRenderer.a(SourceFile:886)
        at com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSurfaceView.onTouchEvent(SourceFile:637)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1612)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2494)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2274)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8025)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4668)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4556)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4150)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4176)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4184)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4318)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4150)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4176)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4184)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4150)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6302)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6240)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6211)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6382)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:177)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6355)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6401)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.Z
```

For now, all initialization and displaying is being performed in the same activity. The onCreate() method is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapResDirPath = getFilesDir() + "/" + "SKMaps";

    Log.i(TAG, "Preparing maps in " + mapResDirPath);
    final SKPrepareMapTextureThread prepThread = new SKPrepareMapTextureThread(this, mapResDirPath, "SKMaps.zip", this);
    prepThread.start();

    while (!mapsPrepared) {
        Common.sleep(100);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Maps have been prepared. Continuing");
    SKMapsInitSettings settings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
    //settings.setMapResourcesPaths(mapResDirPath, new SKMapViewStyle(mapResDirPath + "daystyle/", "daystyle.json"));
    settings.setMapResourcesPaths(mapResDirPath, new SKMapViewStyle(mapResDirPath + "/daystyle/", "daystyle.json"));


    final SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings = settings.getAdvisorSettings();
    advisorSettings.setLanguage("en");
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("en");
    settings.setAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);

    SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(this, settings, "<my api key>");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_skobbler);
    SKMapViewHolder mapViewGroup  = (SKMapViewHolder)findViewById(R.id.skobbler_main_map);
    mapViewGroup.setScaleViewEnabled(true);
    mapView = mapViewGroup.getMapSurfaceView();

    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapZoomingEnabled(true);
    mapView.setPositionAsCurrent(new SKCoordinate(-33.0, 18.0), 1.0f, true);
}
```

As a test, I've implemented SKPrepareMapTextureListener, SKMapSurfaceListener and SKMapUpdateListener but the error still persists.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. I just realised I implemented SKMapSurfaceListener but never called SKMapSurfaceView.setMapSurfaceListener()